# How to round numbers in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I have a graph that instead of using count() as Y axis I used percentage. I would like to show only the round number and see the whole number 39%, 24%, 37%.

```
activities = pd.DataFrame({'Activity': ['Sleeping','Sleeping', 'Eating', 'TV', 'Work', 'Exercise'],
                           'Time': [8, 2, 4, 8, 2,2]})

bars =alt.Chart(activities).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count(*)'
).transform_calculate(
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('Activity'),
    alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%'))
)

text = bars.mark_text(
align='right',
baseline='middle',
dx=3, # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
dy=-4
).encode(
text='sum(pct):Q'
)
#Change size of graph
Qs2 = (bars + text).properties(
width=800,
height=300,
title=plot_title4
).configure_axis(
labelFontSize=20,
titleFontSize=20,
)
Qs2[enter image description here][1]
```

[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iVf2.png)
[Desired Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW6eC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

add Afer = alt.Y(.....)
alt.Tooltip(['sum(pct):Q'],format=',.0f', title="Days to respond to a tender")

and add after mark_text:
encode(
text=alt.Text("sum(pct):Q", format=",.0f")

```py
bars =alt.Chart(r).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count(*)'
).transform_calculate(
    pct='100 / datum.total'
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('sum(pct):Q'),
    alt.Y('shot_first'),
    alt.Tooltip(['sum(pct):Q'],format=',.2f', title="Days to respond to a tender")
)

text = bars.mark_text(
align='left',
baseline='middle',
dx=3, # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
dy=-4
).encode(
        text=alt.Text("sum(pct):Q", format=",.0f", "%")
)


#Change size of graph
Qs2 = (bars + text).properties(
width=800,
height=300,
title=plot_title4
).configure_axis(
labelFontSize=25,
titleFontSize=25,
)
Qs2
```

Answer (score 2):

in order to show labels as % you can write even shorter code:

```
text=alt.Text("sum(pct):Q", format=".0%")
```

I would suggest a couple other improvements for your chart -

- change angle of axis X labels to 0 for better readability,
- add more descriptive axes name for Y,
- reduce number of ticks.

I don't fully understand why you want to move bar labels to the right. but it's your choice.

```
activities = pd.DataFrame({'Activity': ['Sleeping','Sleeping', 'Eating', 'TV', 'Work', 'Exercise'],
                           'Time': [8, 2, 4, 8, 2,2]})

bars =alt.Chart(activities).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count(*)'
).transform_calculate(
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('Activity', title=""),
    #below we will clean axis Y - by reducing number of ticks, and setting min and max for the axe
    alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%', tickCount=4), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 0.4]), title="% of activities")
)



text = bars.mark_text(
align='left',
baseline='middle',
dx=3, # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
dy=-4,
fontSize=15,
).encode(
        text=alt.Text("sum(pct):Q", format=".0%")
)

#Change size of graph
Qs2 = (bars + text)
Qs2.properties(
    width=800,
    height=300,    
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=25,
    titleFontSize=25,
    labelAngle=0 #change the angle of labels for better readability
)
```

[image: updated chart]